# Kivy scrollable label: impossible to read the beginning and the end of the label

Tags: python, scroll, kivy

I have these scrollable labels but I can't read the very beginning and the very end of them(the alphabet starting with 1 and the one starting with 8).

Another issue is that the scrollview starts in the center and jumps back automatically to the center when the scroll is released. It would be better to have it display the left part and let the label where I have stop to scroll.

I use python 3.6 and Kivy 1.9.2.dev0 and my code has to be in python (no .kv file or builder)

```py
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
# from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        layout_pop  = GridLayout (cols=3)
        for i in range(3):
            l = Label(
                 text="1abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_2abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_3abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_4abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_5abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_6abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_7abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_8abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
                 font_size=15,
                 color=(1,1,3,1), 
                 size_hint_x= None,
                 width=600)  
            l.bind(size_hint_min_x=l.setter('width'))
            scroll = ScrollView(size_hint=(None, None), size=(200, 30))
            scroll.add_widget(l)
            layout_pop.add_widget(scroll)
        return layout_pop


Test().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply had to use `l.bind(texture_size=l.setter('size'))`. That fixed the 2 issues.
This is the updated def function:

```
def build(self):
    layout_pop  = GridLayout (cols=3)
    for i in range(3):
        l = Label( 
            text="1abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_2abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_3abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_4abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_5abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_6abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_7abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_8abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \n1abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_2abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_3abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_4abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_5abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_6abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_7abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_8abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 
            font_size=15, 
            color=(1,1,3,1), 
            size_hint_x= None)
        l.bind(texture_size=l.setter('size'))
        l.bind(size_hint_min_x=l.setter('width'))
        scroll = ScrollView(size_hint=(None, None), size=(200, 30))
        scroll.add_widget(l)
        layout_pop.add_widget(scroll)
    return layout_pop
```